# git clone hangs within Azure DevOps build task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

For some reason performing a `git clone` command within a Azure DevOps build pipeline always hangs. This includes `git submodule update --init --recursive` because I think in the background it simply calls `git clone` on the submodule's repo URL.

The parent repository and the submodules exist in "Azure Repos Git".

So the first phase in the build task is "Get sources" and within this phase i'm able to add command line tasks and call `git tag`, `git branch`, `git commit`, etc. But for some reason it hangs if I try to call `git clone`.

Seems like it doesn't want to communicate with any other repository other than the repository specified in the "Get sources" phase properties.

**Is this a limitation?**

**Anyone know how I can get git clone to work in an Azure DevOps build task?**

There are no errors, it simply hangs on any call to `git clone`.

My permissions look right:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was right in front of my face. Under the Get sources properties, way at the bottom:

[image]

Here's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=vsts#checkout-submodules).

Comment: the amount of time I may or may not have spent on this is equal to the amount of gratitude I have for your answer.